# How can I make a LayoutAnimationController animate every view in a GridView?

Tags: android, gridview

I have a GridView and on a button pressed, the GridView fades in, one of its Views at a time. The code for this is simply:

```
Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.fade_in);
LayoutAnimationController layoutAnimationController = new LayoutAnimationController(fadeIn);
friendsGridView.setLayoutAnimation(layoutAnimationController);
friendsGridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

This works really nicely but, if during the animation process I swipe down, all of the views are suddenly visible and the animation seems to be cut short. I know that the GridView recycles views, and so perhaps this is not the optimal solution for me, but when the button is pressed I want EVERY view to be faded in one at a time (I don't expect the size of the GridView to exceed ~30 views), and if you swipe down to something that has not been faded in yet, you will have to wait for it to fade in (fadeIn duration is only 200 and with <30 views I don't think this is a problem).

I am wondering if it is possible to use that based off of the code that I have above? Or for my purposes would I need to create some sort of `ScrollView` and animate each of it's children individually?

EDIT: For my purpose an equally plausible and maybe even better solution would be to pause the app until the views on the screen are all faded in. Since most screens will only support a small subset of the maximum 30 views, this should take no time at all. So I suppose the alternate question is how can I pause any user interaction until the above is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve the second end by adding the following earlier within the code:

```
gridView.setLayoutAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        gridView.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        gridView.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }
});
```

Unlike the animation listeners, this is only fired off only once after the entire `LayoutAnimationController` has completed it's task. It makes the GridView unseable to the user until the animation is complete.